# Trouble extracting elements from a nested psych list using dplyr and purrr

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr, psych

I have a nested dataframe in R to which I apply a function from the package psych. I add the resulting list to the dataframe. I would now like to create a new column which contains a specific element from that list. In principle, I know how this works, but for some reason the resulting list is NULL. I can verify that the list I extract from is not empty though, so I wonder what the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated. Reproducible example below.

```
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)

tibble( A = c( 1, 2, 3, 4),
        B = c( 1, 2, 3 ,4),
        C = c( 2, 3, 3, 5),
        group = c( 1, 1, 1, 1))%>%
      group_by( group) %>%
      nest() %>% 
      mutate( ICC_results = data %>% map( ICC)) -> df

# Now I would like to add a variable containing a numeric element from the list, so ideally use map_dbl, but that gives an error because extracting any element from the list results in an empty list

 df  %>%
       mutate( ICC3 = ICC_results %>% map( 9)) 

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   group [1]
  group data             ICC_results ICC3  
  <dbl> <list>           <list>      <list>
1     1 <tibble [4 x 3]> <psych>     <NULL>

# I can verify that the element I am looking to extract is not empty
df %>%
  select( ICC_results) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  str()

List of 76
 $ ICC_results.results.type1       : chr "ICC1"
 $ ICC_results.results.type2       : chr "ICC2"
 $ ICC_results.results.type3       : chr "ICC3"
 $ ICC_results.results.type4       : chr "ICC1k"
 $ ICC_results.results.type5       : chr "ICC2k"
 $ ICC_results.results.type6       : chr "ICC3k"
 $ ICC_results.results.ICC1        : num 0.857
 $ ICC_results.results.ICC2        : num 0.862
 $ ICC_results.results.ICC3        : num 0.949
 $ ICC_results.results.ICC4        : num 0.947
 $ ICC_results.results.ICC5        : num 0.949
 $ ICC_results.results.ICC6        : num 0.982
 ....
```

Comment: which element do you want to extract from `str(df$ICC_results)` ?

Comment: The 9th element. I've tried both `map(9)` and `map("ICC_results.results.ICC3")`, and all variants like extract, pluck, and the likes... Nothing works.

Comment: @Waldi: Thanks for the hint, I think I figured it out.

Comment: Great, something like `df$ICC_results[[1]]$results$ICC[[3]]`?

Comment: Something along the lines of what @tmfmnk suggested, but less beautiful. So I spare the world and refrain from posting it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 nest() %>% 
 mutate(ICC_results = map_dbl(data, 
                              ~ pluck(ICC(.), "results") %>% 
                               filter(type == "ICC3") %>%
                               pull(ICC)))

  group data             ICC_results
  <dbl> <list>                 <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [4 × 3]>       0.949
```